# Abrir página ao clicar em Ok - SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Estou fazendo um teste com o plugin `SweetAlert`, e gostaria de abrir uma página ao clicar no `ok`, mas não consegui fazer.

Fiz um teste usando `setTimeout`, mas ficou muita gambiarra...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="sweet/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sweet/dist/sweetalert.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            swal("Sucesso!", "TAG nº<? print($ordem); ?> editada.", "success");
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = '/manutencao/EditarTag.php';
            }, 2000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) podes usar um objeto seguido da função a executar quando o botão for premido. Poderia ser algo assim:

```
swal({
    title: "Sucesso!",
    text: "TAG nº<? print($ordem); ?> editada.",
    type: "success",
    closeOnConfirm: false // ou mesmo sem isto
}, function() {
    window.location = 'http://wikipedia.com';
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ncyz6tn3/

Comment: Isso ai Sérgio. Obrigado pela documentação, não tinha visto.

Comment: @Diego de nada. No jsFiddle não deu para usar `window.location` porque eles bloqueiam, mas fica o link.